# CodeIgniter - Every page is marqued first page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination, continuous-integration

I got a problem on my CI.
I’m using CI pagination, however when I got to page 2/3… the first page still marqued.
**Everytime I change of page the content change too, but the first page still marked 1**
The function URL is :

**uri->segment(4)
www.site.com/controller/function/index/1(page number)**

**Function :**

```
$this->load->helper("url");
        $limite = 6;
        if ($this->uri->segment(4) == ""):
            $data['start'] = 0;
        else:
            $data['start'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $data['start'] = ($data['start']-1)*$limite;
        endif;

        //Carregar a livraria paginação
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //URL Base
        $config['base_url']     =   base_url().'item_shop/armaduras/index/';
        //Total de registos
        $config['total_rows']   =   $this->item_shop_model->contar_armaduras($limite,$data['start']);
        //Numero de links
        $config['num_links']    =   5;
        // Segmento que conterá o parâmetro de incremento
        $config['uri_sigments'] =   4;
        $config['per_page']     =   $limite;
        $config['first_page']   =   1;

        // Configuracoes de estilo da url
        $config['first_link'] = '<<';
        $config['last_link'] = '>>';
        $config['next_link'] = '>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;     

        // Iniciamos as configuracoes e criamos o link para o acesso
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']     =   $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['items']          =   $this->item_shop_model->select_all_armaduras($limite,$data['start']);
        $data['title']          =   "HeroM2 Servidor Privado de Metin2";
        $this->load->view('shop-2',$data);
```

When I use the index function controller, it’s work perfectly :

**uri->segment(3)
www.site.com/controller/index/1**

**Index Function :**

```
$this->load->helper("url");
        //Limite de registos
        $limite = 6;
        if ($this->uri->segment(3) == ""):
            $data['start'] = 0;
        else:
            $data['start'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['start'] = ($data['start']-1)*$limite;
        endif;

        //Carregar a livraria paginação
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        //URL Base
        $config['base_url']     =   base_url().'item_shop/index/';
        //Total de registos
        $config['total_rows']   =   $this->item_shop_model->contar_espadas($limite,$data['start']);
        //Numero de links
        $config['num_links']    =   5;
        // Segmento que conterá o parâmetro de incremento
        $config['uri_sigments'] =   3;
        $config['per_page']     =   $limite;
        $config['first_page']   =   1;

        // Configuracoes de estilo da url
        $config['first_link'] = '<<';
        $config['last_link'] = '>>';
        $config['next_link'] = '>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;     

        // Iniciamos as configuracoes e criamos o link para o acesso
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']     =   $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['items'] = $this->item_shop_model->select_all_espadas($limite,$data['start']);
        $data['title'] = "HeroM2 Servidor Privado de Metin2";
        $this->load->view('shop-1',$data);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$config['uri_segment']` from 3 to 4.

**EDIT**

Wrong name used, changed `uri_sigments` to `uri_segment`

Comment: Thats not the problem I've already changed to 4 and nothing happens.. |:

Comment: Didn't notice this before but you have segment spelled wrong, should be `$config['uri_segment']`, see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I've changed to uri_segment, however I sill with the same problem :|